# I need to build OCR scrapers

Tags: ocr, screen-scraping, uipath

**I want to be able to build OCR scraping applications** which are able to :

1. automatically detect when predetermined softwares are running on our computer (examples of softwares we need to scrap : web browsers, or any software window like for example word, a media player, powerpoint, a gaming software or whatever...). It should be able to detect when this window is moved in the user's screen and follow it. Sometimes a window can temporarily hide or overlap the scanned window : our scraper must be able to deal with these situations and continue scanning even in this case.
2. when it has detected one of the predetermined software is running, it should automatically open one specific excel files to export the data.
3. do an OCR scan of this window in real time and when a predetermined event happens in the scanned window, launch an extraction of the data (in a timelapse faster than 1 second since the predetermined event happened)
4. the data might be : text, numbers, OCR recognition of images, or simply the colour of predetermined pixels in the window.
5. extract the information and paste it into specific cells of an opened excel sheet. (please, let me know the other destination output formats your softwares allows).
6. call a macro in the excel output file after each pasting.
7. save a copy of each pasting in excel files stored in a determined directory (this action should not require to open excel when a new copy must be saved and stored, it should be done in the background).
8. several scrapers should be able to work at the same time on the same computer. For example, a situation with 2 scrapers extracting data from a gaming software + 1 scraper extracting the subtitles from a movie on VLC at the same time should be possible.

**So at this stage, I was wondering if there were existing softwares that would allow me to build such scraping applications? (given that I don't code).**

I googled it and found uipath, but I have no idea what it's worth.

The other option would be to hire someone, but i'd like to be able to do that myself in the future.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would need a professional to do this - or at least use some time to understand the program. UiPath would most likely be able do to this, but it will take some time to do without any experience.

I dont think UiPath is able to have multiple robots or jobs running at the same time - so being able to scrape multiple programs at once would be tricky to do.